# Invalid Date Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have looked around but am struggling to understand this issue.

In my spreadsheet I have a cell that contains the date like 29/02/16 - 06/03/16.

I am looking to split this and set the two dates as two different variables in Google Apps Script. However using this code:

```
var date = new Date("B4");
```

I am getting returned an Invalid Date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The string "B4" is not a date. If you want to convert the string in cell B4 into a date use:

```
var iDate = new Date(sheet.getRange("B4").getValue());
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue I am now getting is that this is returning the date as Sun Mar 06 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT) and I need it as YYYY-MM-DD format. Is this possible?

Comment: The variable now contains a date, not a string. The date can be displayed in various formats - change the display format of the involved cells.

Comment: Thank you. How do I change how the date it shown in the debugger though? I will be using the date variables to enter into a URL that the script pulls data from an external API.